# Problem removing cookie in servlet

Tags: java, http, servlets, cookies

I trying to remove a cookie in a servlet with this code

```
Cookie minIdCookie = null;

for (Cookie c : req.getCookies()) {
    if (c.getName().equals("iPlanetDirectoryPro")) {
        minIdCookie = c;
        break;
    }
}

if (minIdCookie != null) {
    minIdCookie.setMaxAge(0);
    minIdCookie.setValue("");
    minIdCookie.setPath("/");
    res.addCookie(minIdCookie);
}

res.flushBuffer();
```

But this gives no effect and no change in the cookie properties.

I've also tried adding a cookie in this servlet and this works fine.

Why is it that I can not change the properties of an existing cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the cookie I wanted to remove had a path that was "/admin" and my logout servlet had the path "/admin/logoutServlet". When I get the cookie from the request the path is set to null. So when I add the cookie the path is set to "/admin/" as my servletIf I created a cookie with the path "/admin/" the servlet was able to remove it.

I solved the problem by explisitly setting the path of the cookie before adding it to the response.

```
minIdCookie.setMaxAge(0);
minIdCookie.setPath("/");
res.addCookie(minIdCookie);
```

But I don't understand why the path is null.

Comment: Path is always null because it's only needed in the response. When a request comes in, it's not needed (or so they claim), and therefore not set.

Answer (score 7):

You should not change the path. This would change the cookie identity. If the cookie were set for a path like `/foo` and you change this to `/`, then the client won't associate the changed cookie with the original cookie anymore. A cookie is identified by the name and the path.

Just setting maxage to 0 ought to be enough.

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) { // Yes, this can return null! The for loop would otherwise throw NPE.
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals("iPlanetDirectoryPro")) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to ensure that you're reading/testing the cookie in the subsequent **new** request, not in the current request.

Comment: The problem was that I tried to change a cookie with the path "/admin" and my servlets path is "/admin/". is it not possible to remove a cookie on another path or another domain?

Comment: You can remove a cookie on another path of the same domain. You just have to set its maxage to 0. You should not change the path. It would only create a new cookie (which in turn would immediately disappear because maxage is 0). You cannot access cookies on another domain. This is a security restriction. You can at highest access cookies of another subdomain. You only need to set domain as `.example.com` instead of `example.com`.

Comment: @BalusC Can you suggest me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49975485/cookie-is-adding-twice-in-browser-when-page-is-loaded

Answer (score 4):

I understand this is a few years old now, but the answer BalusC gave above isn't entirely correct, nor does Stefan's accepted answer really give all the details.

The path and domain will always be null when you retrieve cookies in Java because they are only necessary in the response for the client browser. However, if you're in the same security domain (regardless of the path), you still have the rights to delete them. Unfortunately, because the path is not included you can't delete the cookie now without explicitly knowing that path. Simply using the same cookie name, but a different path will not work. Those are considered two different cookies, and you will find that instead of deleting the cookie, you just created another one on a different path.

The other problem most developers have is they try to check for the absence of cookies before the response has been committed. A cookie is not removed until the client browser can read the response and remove it from the file system. If you forward to another servlet with the hope that you have deleted a cookie you will find it still exists (since the initial request is the same). In this sense request attributes are a much better option.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time the problem is with path of the cookie.
So take care that you specify the path when creating a cookie.
And then use the same path while discarding a cookie.
The concept of path is

> public String getPath() public void setPath(String path) These methods
>   get or set the path to which the cookie applies. If you don’t specify
>   a path, the browser returns the cookie only to URLs in or below the
>   directory containing the page that sent the cookie. For example, if
>   the server sent the cookie from
>   //ecommerce.site.com/toys/specials.html, the browser would send
>   the cookie back when connecting to
>   //ecommerce.site.com/toys/bikes/beginners.html, but not to
>   //ecommerce.site.com/cds/classical.html. The setPath method can
>   be used to specify something more general. For example,
>   someCookie.setPath("/") specifies that all pages on the server should
>   receive the cookie. The path specified must include the current page;
>   that is, you may specify a more general path than the default, but not
>   a more specific one. So, for example, a servlet at
>   //host/store/cust-service/request could specify a path of /store/
>   (since /store/ includes /store/cust-service/) but not a path of
>   /store/cust-service/returns/ (since this directory does not include
>   /store/cust-service/).

to get more info of path and cookie relate properties you can visit [here](http://www.dineshonjava.com/search/label/Servlet).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to be using `null` instead of empty string. ie. change 
`minIdCookie.setValue("");` to `minIdCookie.setValue(null);`